# SFTP via Terminal Error

Tags: ssh, sftp

I cant connect to a server via sftp any more, I could yesterday. Here is the full sftp -vvv log, maybe you could help me out? Tried deleting ~/.ssh, tried hosts.allow / hosts.deny. No solution at all.

Any suggestions?

```
sftp -vvvvvv -P 1313 user@xx.dyndns.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.dyndns.org [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 1313.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Try from another computer. If it has the same problem, your computer is not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Aaron - this is normal behavior.  See [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=961586#p961586) - I also just tested a successful SFTP connection with -vvvvv, and got the same message.

I think you should check /var/log/auth.log (if Debian/Ubuntu/etc.) or /var/log secure (if RH, Fedora, etc.) on the remote computer.  You should see a more informative error.

Also check the file permissions on the files on the remote server - ~/.ssh, ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  They should be readable by your user, and authorized_keys should have 600 as its permissions.  Can you still SSH to that server?